# how to extract all tokens include null value from a string in C

Tags: c

Below code uses `strtok` function to extract tokens from string by delimeter ','.

ex.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   char string[200] = "$GNGNS,103600.01,5114.51176,N,00012.29380,W,45.6,,,V*00";
   // Extract the first token
   char * token = strtok(string, ",");
   // loop through the string to extract all other tokens
   while( token != NULL ) {
      printf( " %s\n", token ); //printing each token
      token = strtok(NULL, ",");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
 $GNGNS
 103600.01
 5114.51176
 N
 00012.29380
 W
 45.6
 V*00
```

Here the null value `,,,` between `45.6` and `V*00` are ignored. How can I print all tokens eventhrough it is null? like:

```
$GNGNS
103600.01
5114.51176
N
00012.29380
W   
45.6


V*00
```

Comment: On Linux or Mac, you can use [`strsep`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html). For portability, you might need to include an [open-source implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/ics-mr0/libc/string/strsep.c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write something simple instead of strtok.

```
char **split(char **argv, int *argc, char *string, const char delimiter, int allowempty)
{
    *argc = 0;
    do
    {
        if(*string && (*string != delimiter || allowempty))
        {
            argv[(*argc)++] = string;
        }
        while(*string && *string != delimiter) string++;
        if(*string) *string++ = 0;
        if(!allowempty) 
            while(*string && *string == delimiter) string++;
    }while(*string);
    return argv;
}

int main() {
   char string[200] = "$GNGNS,103600.01,5114.51176,N,00012.29380,W,45.6,,,V*00";

    char *args[20];
    int nargs;

    split(args, &nargs, string, ',', 1);

    for(int x = 0; x < nargs; x++)
    {
        printf("ARG[%2d] = `%s`\n", x, args[x]);
    }

   return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vKqP4hvG4

Output:

```
ARG[ 0] = `$GNGNS`
ARG[ 1] = `103600.01`
ARG[ 2] = `5114.51176`
ARG[ 3] = `N`
ARG[ 4] = `00012.29380`
ARG[ 5] = `W`
ARG[ 6] = `45.6`
ARG[ 7] = ``
ARG[ 8] = ``
ARG[ 9] = `V*00`
```

Comment: thanks. I get a warning 'line 262: warning #225-D: function "split" declared implicitly'
 'line 401: warning #161-D: declaration is incompatible with previous "split" (declared at line 262)'

Comment: @leilei: Did you call the function before it was defined? In that case, you must add a [prototype declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration) at the start of your file, immediately after all `#include` directives: `char **split(char **argv, int *argc, char *string, const char delimiter, int allowempty);` That way, the compiler will have all the information it needs to know about the function for now, and you can call it. The actual definition of the function (with the function body) can then come at a later point in the program (or in another file).

Comment: @leilei: The second warning messages seems to imply that you have several incompatible declarations of the function `split`. Since the first and second warning messages seem to originate in line 262, it sounds to me that you are doing something very strange in that line. Can you please show us the contents of line 262? On the other hand, maybe the second warning is just a consequence of the problem mentioned in the first warning, and it may go away if you fix the problem that is causing the first warning.

Answer (score 2):

The function `strtok` does not consider an empty token to be a valid token. However, you can easily solve the problem using [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) instead of `strtok`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    const char *const string =
        "$GNGNS,103600.01,5114.51176,N,00012.29380,W,45.6,,,V*00";

    const char *p = string, *q;

    //continue looping until there are no more ',' characters
    while ( ( q = strchr( p, ',' ) ) != NULL )
    {
        //print token
        printf( "%.*s\n", (int)(q-p), p );

        //make p point one character past the ',', which is the
        //first character of the next token, unless the next
        //token is empty
        p = q + 1;
    }

    //print last token
    printf( "%s\n", p );
}
```

Output of program:

```
$GNGNS
103600.01
5114.51176
N
00012.29380
W
45.6


V*00
```

This solution also has the advantage that the string is allowed to be read-only. Therefore, I was able to define the string as a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) instead of an array (I didn't have to, though). This would not have been possible with `strtok`, because that function is destructive in the sense that it overwrites the delimiters with null terminating characters, which requires the string to be writable.